# Issues with failback for logical replication using postgres

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication

I am using PostgreSQL 13 to set up logical replication. When the original active node (A) becomes the secondary, the prior secondary(B) which is now active node needs to sync to the (A) node.

To summarize the issue:

Node A is active and fails at some point of time. Node B takes over and now running is active and accepting I/O from application. Now when Node A is recovered from failure and ready to become active again. In order to happen this Node A is trying to get the data which may be have been added while Node A was down. To get the this data Node A is creating a subscription to Node B which is now acting as a publisher. Issue is that this subscription on Node A fails as Node A already has some data before it went down and this data results in conflicts.

So what are my options here?